# Speeding up OpenCV's input response

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing my first `OpenCV` program and just playing around with some image manipulation using the camera on my Macbook. The code below just shows the camera and allows me to press `0` for the normal view, `1`, `2`, or `3` to change from GRB and `4` to change it to black and white.

Unfortunately, I have to hold down the key for it to respond. What causes this delay and how can I get the code to be more responsive to input?

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat channel(Mat A, int ich) {
    Mat Channel[3];
    Mat B = A.clone();
    split(B, Channel);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if( ich-1 != i ) Channel[i] = Mat::zeros(B.rows, B.cols, CV_8UC1);
    }
    merge(Channel, 3, B);
    return B;
}

Mat BW(Mat A) {
    Mat B;
    B = A.clone();
    cvtColor( A, B, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    return B;
}
int main() {
    int waitCount = 1; // wait for this many milliseconds to check for input
    VideoCapture stream1(0);

    namedWindow("cam", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    if( !stream1.isOpened() ) { 
        cout << "Cannot open camera!" << endl;
    }   

    int showKind = 0;

    Mat cameraFrame; // showKind = 0
    Mat grey; // showkind = 4
    while( true ) { 
        /// read the cameraFrame
        stream1.read(cameraFrame);

        /// show the cameraFrame
        if( showKind == 0 ) imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
        else if( showKind > 0 && showKind < 4 ) imshow("cam", channel(cameraFrame, showKind));
        else if( showKind == 4 ) imshow("cam", BW(cameraFrame) );
        else {
            cout << "ERROR: Unknown showKind = " << showKind << endl;
        }   

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// check for input
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // close down
        if( waitKey(waitCount) == 27 ) { 
            cout << "ESC pressed ... exiting" << endl;
            break;
        }   
        // convert showKind
        else if( waitKey(waitCount) == 48 ) { 
            cout << "Showkind changed to 0" << endl;
            showKind = 0;
        }   
        else if( waitKey(waitCount) == 49 ){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 1" << endl;
            showKind = 1;
        }   
        else if( waitKey(waitCount) == 50 ){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 2" << endl;
            showKind = 2;
        }   
        else if( waitKey(waitCount) == 51 ){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 3" << endl;
            showKind = 3;
        }   
        else if( waitKey(waitCount) == 52 ){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 4" << endl;
            showKind = 4;
        }   
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by your cascade calls to `waitKey`. You can call `waitKey` only once, and store the `key` pressed, like:

```
int key = waitKey(waitCount);
if (key == 27) {
    cout << "ESC pressed ... exiting" << endl;
    break;
}
// convert showKind
else if (key == 48) {
    cout << "Showkind changed to 0" << endl;
    showKind = 0;
}
else if (key == 49){
    cout << "Showkind changed to 1" << endl;
    showKind = 1;
}
else if (key == 50){
    cout << "Showkind changed to 2" << endl;
    showKind = 2;
}
else if (key == 51){
    cout << "Showkind changed to 3" << endl;
    showKind = 3;
}
else if (key == 52){
    cout << "Showkind changed to 4" << endl;
    showKind = 4;
}
```

---

- Using a `switch` statement could also be clearer.
- You can simply use `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` instead of all your `#include`
- to set a matrix to a given value, you can use `setTo`, so `Channel[i].setTo(0);`
- You do not need to initialize matrices that are `OutputArray` of OpenCV's functions.

So here the full code with a few improvements:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat channel(const Mat& A, int ich) {
    Mat Channel[3];
    Mat B;
    split(A, Channel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (ich - 1 != i) Channel[i].setTo(0);
    }
    merge(Channel, 3, B);
    return B;
}

Mat BW(const Mat& A) {
    Mat B;
    cvtColor(A, B, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return B;
}
int main() {
    int waitCount = 1; // wait for this many milliseconds to check for input
    VideoCapture stream1(0);

    namedWindow("cam", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    if (!stream1.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Cannot open camera!" << endl;
    }

    int showKind = 0;

    Mat cameraFrame; // showKind = 0
    Mat grey; // showkind = 4
    while (true) {
        /// read the cameraFrame
        stream1 >> cameraFrame;


        /// show the cameraFrame
        if (showKind == 0) imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
        else if (showKind > 0 && showKind < 4) imshow("cam", channel(cameraFrame, showKind));
        else if (showKind == 4) imshow("cam", BW(cameraFrame));
        else {
            cout << "ERROR: Unknown showKind = " << showKind << endl;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// check for input1
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // close down
        int key = waitKey(waitCount);
        if (key == 27) {
            cout << "ESC pressed ... exiting" << endl;
            break;
        }
        // convert showKind
        else if (key == 48) {
            cout << "Showkind changed to 0" << endl;
            showKind = 0;
        }
        else if (key == 49){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 1" << endl;
            showKind = 1;
        }
        else if (key == 50){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 2" << endl;
            showKind = 2;
        }
        else if (key == 51){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 3" << endl;
            showKind = 3;
        }
        else if (key == 52){
            cout << "Showkind changed to 4" << endl;
            showKind = 4;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```